# How to split a multi-test dll into separate dll's per TestClass for Azure DevOps multi-agent test parallelization

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, msbuild-task, csc

Azure DevOps has the ability to run Visual Studio tests across [multiple agents in parallel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops#massively-parallel-testing-by-combining-parallel-pipeline-jobs-with-parallel-test-execution). I would like to take advantage of this, but when I updated my build pipeline to run across multiple agents with the `Based on past running time of tests` strategy, each agent is assigned at least one **entire** test assembly (i.e. TestSuite1.dll, TestSuite2.dll, etc.). This means there is a huge amount of opportunity to parallelize lost for each of our independent MSTest `TestClass`'es, because our tests have been designed to have class level execution scope.

Our Azure DevOps pipeline succeeds with parallelization across agents per base test assembly, but obviously we'd prefer slicing per each distinct test in our test assembly, so **what's the best strategy to achieve splitting each derived TestClass across agents** (preferably without refactoring our entire test code)?

Notes:

I've generated xml to 'successfully' build exactly one `TestClass` into its own .dll and then referencing just that .dll in the `Visual Studio Test` task, but there's just a bazillion assembly referencing\redirect issues once the actual class starts to execute past the `[AssemblyInitialize]` code. Since I have the build output for our entire solution, I do have access to the `csc` command  run for the entire test assembly, but again, haven't been able to test it yet and I assume just referencing the configuration parameters in it would be brittle to future changes. Also, I don't think executing the `Visual Studio Test` task with anything but `Select tests using Test Assemblies` will get the benefit of the `Based on past running time of tests` slicing strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generating test assemblies seems crazy, but you could possibly move all the base plumbing logic into a "test framework" assembly and then programmatically generating test assemblies for each TestClass:

```
csc TestClassName.cs -reference:TestFramework.dll
```

## Or...

Rather than trying to reorganize the tests programmatically, it might make more sense to manually split your tests into different logical groupings. Ideally, you'd split them at the namespace or another significant boundary. You could also, in theory, reorganize them into arbitrary buckets (fast/slow, or 0,1,2,3) and move test classes of equal duration into the appropriate bucket to achieve the desired timing balance. Eg (Namespace.0.Tests.dll, Namespace.1.Tests.dll, Namespace.2.Tests.dll) Admittedly, the discoverability of unit tests will suffer.

## Or....

The Jez Humble Continous Delivery advice applies here: "if it hurts, do it more often". What you're describing sounds painful, and you should drill into that pain instead of trying to solve it with more pain (like stomping on a toe to alleviate bumped elbow).

The Azure DevOps team went through a similar revolution: they had a number of tests using a TestHarness that they wanted to move away from. The labeled all their legacy tests and put together a long-term strategy to move away from that model by a set date. Your approach could be similar:

1. Create an assembly where the tests represent an ideal strategy. These tests should be able to run in parallel with isolation from one another and would be able to take advantage of [strategies #1 and #2 listed in the multi-agent article you shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/parallel-testing-vstest?view=azure-devops#massively-parallel-testing-by-combining-parallel-pipeline-jobs-with-parallel-test-execution)
2. Move anything you can to the above assembly. For everything else, make plans to move them at a later date.
3. Report on progress with KPI: Build Length, # of Tests using the old framework. Then Repeat 1 and 2 until you've addressed your pain with a more efficient model.